# Using SklearnTutorial and unable to undertand the output of vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

Is the output part of my 20newsgroups_train data? or is it from a default library? Because the words like 'zz_g9q3' dont make sense.
currently using 20newsgroups_train dataset and 20newsgroups_test datasets

Input:

```
vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer()
vectors_test=vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()[-50:])
```

Output:

```
['zyra' 'zysec' 'zysgm3r' 'zysv' 'zyt' 'zyu' 'zyv' 'zyxel' 'zyxel1496b'
 'zz' 'zz20d' 'zz93sigmc120' 'zz_g9q3' 'zzcrm' 'zzd' 'zzg6c' 'zzi776'
 'zzneu' 'zznki' 'zznkj' 'zznkjz' 'zznkzz' 'zznp' 'zzo' 'zzr11' 'zzr1100'
 'zzrk' 'zzt' 'zztop' 'zzy_3w' 'zzz' 'zzzoh' 'zzzz' 'zzzzzz' 'zzzzzzt'
 'ªl' '³ation'
 'º_________________________________________________º_____________________º'
 'ºnd' 'çait' 'çon' 'ère' 'ée' 'égligent' 'élangea' 'érale' 'ête'
 'íålittin' 'ñaustin' 'ýé']
```

Comment: What is this 20newsgroups_train and test dataset?

Comment: @MathGeek i got the data set from here .  http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/20news-bydate.tar.gz